# Strange behavior of reopen review window: stuck in "side-by-side markdown" view

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am experiencing a strange behavior: In reopen review, when I explore the "revision" tab, I am stuck in "side-by-side markdown" format, and cannot change to any other format (i.e., not to "side-by-side" and not to "inline".

So I'm stuck in [this view](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3278727):

> [image: screen shot]

Whenever I click on "inline" or "side-by-side markdown" I simply get three dots at the right hand of the screens and nothing happens.

Is this a known issue? Is there a fix for it?

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

---

Looking at the network traffic (dev tools), gives me this:

> [image]

I don't really know what to make out of it...

Comment: Press shift+F5 and try again.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an unstable / very slow internet connection?

Comment: If you look at the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19672714/revisions) of the [audit post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3277559) the latest revision was just whitespace, which might not show up in the diff. It also means that the side-by-side diff might be considered incorrect. 

A similar thing happened to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3277805)... 


it looks like "old" or "minor" diffs are being put through the queue, or that combined diffs are being added up to make a substantial one and therefore put it in.

Comment: Might be a plugin/user-script/extension going wild. Disable all of those and see if this helps.

Comment: @Dukeling this behavior is going on for several days now, with multiple net connections. So I guess it is not a slow connection issue.

Comment: @Emrakul I tired that - did not help.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I disabled extensions (all of them) stepped out of "developer mode" and still no change.

Comment: Let's try to debug then - open the dev tools and go to the Network tab. When you click "side by side markdown" for the first time, you see request sent to the server? If so, what is the response sent from server to browser?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thank you for the help. posted a screen shot, I hope I got the right view and info.

Comment: Wow, 404! That's weird.

Comment: OK, right click that item in red and choose "Copy link address". Paste the full URL here and we'll finally see what happened. Example for valid URL: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19672714/f3f7e7d2-c2b7-4585-9ece-18f06bd3f4f0/diff?difftype=SideBySideHtml&_=1383557916421

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd url: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19741547/isions/diff?difftype=SideBySideHtml&_=1383563432814 (sorry it took me so long).

Comment: I passed this up the chain to the dev team.

Comment: looking, fixing...

Comment: @m0sa great! thank you very much!

Comment: @Anna don't you mean down the chain? ;-)

Comment: @m0sa I'm afraid not completely fixed yet: i can switch between "inline" and "side by side" views, but cannot go to "side by side" markdown...

Comment: @Shai the version is still 2013.6.11.1132 on the main site, we have to wait for 2013.6.11.1133 which contains the fix.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ok. I'm not that techy I guess...

Comment: @Shai nothing techy here, the dev who fixed it did say "Watch for revision numbers 2013.6.11.1611 on meta and 2013.6.11.1133 on the sites" :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd tnx for having my back ;)

Comment: @m0sa you're welcome but turns out it didn't help - it's not fixed yet. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproduced in Chrome and IE10 and Found the bug, but only a dev can fix this.

In ordinary revisions page, the HTML structure is: ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19741547/revisions))

> [image]

So when clicking action link, it will go upwards and look for parent element with ID starting with "rev" and take the rest as the desired revision GUID. Works well!

Inside review page (probably any review, not just reopen) it's different: ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3278727))

> [image]

There is no GUID, it find the "revisions" and think "isions" is the GUID, hence that weird URL: `https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19741547/isions/diff?difftype=SideBySideHtml&_=1383563432814`

Comment: Thank you for this debugging effort!

Comment: Thank you for following up on this and directing @m0sa at the right direction!

Comment: @Shai cheers, but you really should accept m0sa's answer, he's the one who actually fixed it. :)

Comment: From the little experience I have with debugging, making the diagnosis is sometimes the most difficult part...

Answer (score 5):

Fix will be rolling out shortly. There was a problem in the revisions.js script which did not go down the designated path in the reopen and close review queue task views.

**Update**

Turns out there were actually issues with the revision switcher in the reopen queue both while reviewing (which was fixed in .1133) and in the review results (fixed in .1134)

Watch for revision numbers `2013.7.11.1612` on meta and `2013.6.11.1134` on the sites.

Comment: Hope "shortly" won't turn to 6-8 weeks! ;)

Comment: Rolling out as we speak...

Comment: Just curious, who decided when there is a deploy? Sometimes I see two in couple of hours, sometimes only once a day. (weekends mostly)

Comment: OK, that's weird. Revision is 2013.11.6.1133 but it's yet fixed, neither is [that other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204381/152859) - what happened?

Comment: 2013.11.7.1134 it is then...

Comment: @m0sa working like charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: @m0sa any idea what happened to [that other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204381/152859)? Maybe he forgot to commit his fix or something?