# Missing space in the user activity report

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, user-interface, recent-activity

In my profile under the [activity report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633423/lorenzo-donati?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) there is a small visual bug: a space is missing between the word "on" and the subsequent word.

See the following image:

> [image]

Comment: Well, I suppose that's better than you suggesting edits on lots of tag wikis prefixed with 'on'!

Comment: @AndrewBarber :-D Well, I hope no one really added an "Onnanotime" tag!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fixed and will be out in the next deploy.

Comment: Has this build been deployed yet?  [Someone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204468/spacing-issue-on-suggested-edit-page) is reporting the same bug.

Comment: [So uh... *wink wink nudge nudge*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148928/orphaned-wiki-edits-have-broken-activity-entry)

Comment: No, it's not fixed.

Comment: It will be fixed (this time for real) in build 2013.11.7.1613 on meta and 2013.11.7.1135 on sites.

Comment: @m0sa fixed indeed. What happened, if I might ask?

Comment: @Sklivvz 's fix did not work as expected, and I woke up before he did :)

Comment: I told you not to touch it, I told you not to touch it, I told you not to touch it you broke it... :-) @m0sa