# Nospace in auto-deleted question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions

Just stumbled over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214853/what-is-the-sof-algorithm-for-generating-the-icons-for-each-user?noredirect=1): (10K only, deleted by an external task due to being migrated away)

> [image]

Can we have the space back in there? There is space in deleted questions having someone (including Community user) deleting them and it's there in answer deleted by nobody. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127547/447356))

Although the symptoms are identical to those described [in this other report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204361/152859), it's a totally diffent page hence the new report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in the most recent deploy.

Long story short: I hate significant whitespace.

Comment: Cheers, you win whitespace lose! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd He has indeed won a whitespace lose.