# Missing space in the user activity report... again

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, recent-activity, whitespace

This is more or less the same bug detailed in *[Missing space in the user activity report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204361/351462)*, only this time it applies to the mobile site.

> In my profile under the [activity report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357935/steven-vascellaro?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) there is a small visual bug: a
>   space is missing between the word "on" and the subsequent word.
>
> See the following image:

[image: Spacing bug on mobile profile]

Comment: Could use more freehand circles.

Comment: @Daedalus Done. I even made them red just for you.